# Do orcs drink water?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, food, orcs

At least in the film version of *Return of the King*, Frodo and Sam run out of water while trekking across Mordor, apparently having been unable to refill their water pouches in the tower or at any other point past there.

We know that the orcs eat regular food, but are they ever shown drinking anything besides orc draught?

Comment: I wonder how much water the orc armies needed in Mordor. It's not like Mordor is running with verdant streams and rivers.

Comment: Gin is my preferred drink, but I will take water if there is nothing else available

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Yes.

In addition to the quote provided by @Randal'Thor, there is also this:

> 'Water, water!' muttered Sam. He had stinted himself, and in his parched mouth his tongue seemed thick and swollen; but for all his care they now had very little left, perhaps half his bottle, and maybe there were still days to go. All would long ago have been spent, if they had  not dared to follow the orc-road. **For at long intervals on that highway cisterns had been built for the use of troops sent in haste through the waterless regions. In one Sam had found some water left, stale, muddied by the orcs, but still sufficient for their desperate case.** Yet that was now a day ago. There was no hope of any more.
> <sub>-*The Return of the King*, Book VI, chapter 3: Mount Doom
>
> (emphasis mine)</sub>

Answer (score 76):

### Yes.

Sam asks the same question, of whether orcs eat and drink or just live on foul air and poison, and Frodo gives him the following answer:

> "No, they eat and drink, Sam. The Shadow that bred them can only mock, it cannot make: not real new things of its own. I don't think it gave life to the orcs, it only ruined them and twisted them; and if they are to live at all, they have to live like other living creatures. Foul waters and foul meats they'll take, if they can get no better, but not poison. They've fed me, and so I'm better off than you. There must be food and water somewhere in this place."
>
> <sub>-- *The Return of the King*, Book VI, Chapter I: *The Tower of Cirith Ungol*</sub>

Comment: They also find the cistern (with a small amount of water in it) on their way to Mount Doom in Mordor.

Comment: @DonyorM I thought that was a natural spring? I don't remember any indication that orcs consumed that water; in fact, wasn't there something about it being unpolluted by orcs?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Quite contrary, it *was* polluted by orcs. And it was indeed a cistern; they were built in long intervals along the road. The book even mentions it was there "for troops sent hastily across the dry land" or something like that (don't have the book on hand to quote exactly).

Answer (score 3):

### They also drank blood

Your question asked if Orcs are "ever shown drinking anything besides orc draught". Other answers here have already showed that Orcs drink water, so I will show something else that they drunk.

From a circa 1968 typescript found among Tolkien's linguistic papers:

> C[ommon]E[ladrin] **khōn-, khond-* was only used of the physical heart, and that was not regarded as or supposed to be a centre of either emotion or thought. Thus when Treebeard uses the adjectives *morimaitë, sincahonda* ' black-handed, flint-hearted' of the Orks, these were both physical in reference - as indeed were all the other adjectives, whatever they may have implied with regard to Orkish minds and characters. *Sincahonda* referred to their immense
> staying power in exertion, marching, running, or climbing, which gave rise to the jesting assertion that their hearts must have been made of some exceedingly hard substance; it did not mean pitiless. **The last adjective 'blood-thirsty' (*serkilixa*) was also literal: the Orks actually drank the blood of their victims.** A compound of similar kind meaning 'hard-hearted, pitiless', would have been in Quenya *ondórëa*.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - "Gender and Sex", footnote</sub>